# Magento v1.9.x subscription spam

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, spam

How is going? Well, I'm facing a subscription spam problem in my Magento Store, but this post is not to find some solution, but so, to understand somethings.

Well, this is what I'm facing:

[image]

**Question 1:**

What is the objective of this?

**Question 2:**

How (probably) this thing are being made?

**Question 3:**

How they are able to subscribe using a Australia address, if Australia is not a allowed country in my store?

**Question 4:**

My subscription pages form inputs deny any non-latin character, how these subscriptions are being made anyway?

I'm deeply curious about this, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: validation of non-latin character happening on server as well, or just in fronted?

Comment: Just front end, @bxN5

Comment: so it sends not from front-end

Comment: How they can do that? @bxN5

Comment: send directly, you can send requests to anyone even thru Linux console with curl

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: What is the objective of this?

They use this subscription to receive emails and then navigate through your website.

> Question 2: How (probably) this thing are being made?

There are a spam bots. They are so extended around Internet.

> Question 3: How they are able to subscribe using a Australia address,
> if Australia is not a allowed country in my store?

Because those bots are able to manipulate your front code and avoid the JS native validation from Magento.

> Question 4: My subscription pages form inputs deny any non-latin
> character, how these subscriptions are being made anyway?

As I told in 3, they can manipulate front code.
I suggest you to put a reCaptcha validation. I used the [Google one](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html). Putting this you will reduce a lot of this spam.
As an alternative you can add a backend validation when processing the form in the controller.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. spamming I guess your magento will send email confirmation to this people
2. bots
3. and 4. you need to check your access logs it will give you and idea what URL they are using.